# aws charging me for dns query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an ec2 instance under the free tier of aws and I am using route 53 hosting with it. In my bills, I am seeing charges for DNS-queries. But I don't get these on other servers I own on other accounts. Is it because I have configured it wrong? Please help

Comment: How did you configure your Route53 ?

Comment: I create a hosted zone with the www.domain-name.in and then added an A record to it. Then I copied the name servers to my website's registrar's panel

Comment: Is this the $0.40/million queries charge? How much have you been charged?

Comment: In your other account, are you using alias record for ELB/CF etc? Queries for alias records are free.

Comment: replying to @JohnRotenstein, yes it is the $0.40/million queries

Comment: replying to @sudo, the only difference in both the accounts is that the one in which I am being charged, I have an extra A record set.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an A-record, then there is a charge ($0.40 per million queries).

However, as per the [Route 53 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/):

> Queries to **Alias records** that are mapped to Elastic Load Balancers, Amazon CloudFront distributions, AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments, and Amazon S3 website buckets are free.

To use this, select "Alias = Yes" and point to one of those resources. (But it appears an EC2 instance is not one of them, unless fronted by a Load Balancer.)

Worst case... pay the 40c!

Comment: As stated above, an Alias record does not apply to an EC2 instance.

Comment: but then, in my other account, I don't have an A record, but still the domain name is launching the site running on my ec2 instance

Comment: How is the domain name in the other account configured? Feel free to Edit your question and provide a screenshot.

Comment: should I add the pic of the route53 config?

Comment: I actually did not add any name servers to the other accounts website registrar, I used the ip there directly. Should I try to do that here?

Comment: If you have a DNS name in the format `ec2-11-22-33-44.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` (or whatever region you're using), then there is no charge for resolution. However, it maps only to that IP address. If you instance is stopped and later started, it might have a different IP address. For this reason, it is always preferable to use a DNS name rather than an IP address.

Comment: yes, the public DNS for my instance is of this format, so how do I use this?

Comment: You simply use it. It's free. But the IP address for your instance might change in future.

Comment: Use it where? Should I put it in instead of the name servers on my domain's registrar?

Comment: On the other account, I did not use the name servers, I only created an A name record with the domain's registrar using the static IP of my ec2 instance. It doesn't seem to be working here

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this cost? Is this cost incurred based on the number is hits my website gets?